# How to differentiate between interactive and non-interactive logins from "echo $-" output in AIX?

Tags: echo, ksh, aix, interactive, non-interactive

I am doing this on AIX (kshell)

When I `echo $-` locally i get the output of `ism`,  and when I run it remote `ssh test_id@sandbox "echo $-"`

```
$ echo $-
ism
```

I am running this from a remote servers to another AIX server

```
ssh test_id@sandbox "echo $-"
himBH
```

Which one of this is interactive and which one in non-interactive

Comment: Whenever you see `i` in the answer, it is interactive. As both `ism` and `himBH` includes `i`, they are both interactive.

Comment: Thank you @LorinczyZsigmond that helps.. Can you please also say what O/P I can expect if it is non-interactive?

Comment: Basically, it process different startup-files (rcfiles) when interactive and when not. Also it can be 'login' and 'not login' so there is four combination: {login,not login}x{interactive,not interactive}

Answer (score 1):

If "interactive" means that there is a terminal associated with the connection, I usually use this method for AIX ksh in my previous company:

```
if tty -s
then
     do-coding-for-sessions-with-terminal
else
     do-nothing
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

As the comments indicated, the presence of an `i` in the `$-` variable indicates that the shell is interactive. To bring in [an answer from Tim Kennedy over at U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46801/117549):

```
case "$-" in
    *i*)
        interactive=1
        ;;
    *)
        not_interactive=1
        ;;
esac
```

The code above uses a [`case` statement](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_05) to see whether the `$-` variable contains an `i` or not.